# Converting String to HTML href tags after parsing

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing

I have a text that I painstakingly parsed to dynamically insert href tags into. the problem I have is that now the tags are show as text and not HTML. Does anybody have any solutions example below:

> Your password must be between 7 http://www.dsfgsd.com and 20
>   characters in length, must contain one or more UPPERCASE letters,
>   "A-Z", must contain one or more lowercase letters, "a-z", must contain
>   one or more numerals, "0-9" and must contain one or more
>   non-alphanumeric character. Your password must be between 7 and 20
>   characters in length, must contain one or more UPPERCASE letters,
>   "A-Z", must contain one or more lowercase letters, "a-z", must contain
>   one or more numerals, "0-9" and must contain one or more
>   non-alphanumeric character. http://www.testing.com

How do I get the links to show as href links and not texts ? Tried Linkify but keep getting JQuery error.

Including Code but not sure if this will help:

```
dataService.getFAQS(params).then(function (data) {
        angular.extend(vm.documents, data);

        var obj={};
        _.each(vm.documents, function (comments) {

            var result = [];
            function getFirstWord(str) {
                        if (str.indexOf(' ') === -1)
                            return str;
                        else
                            return str.substr(0, str.indexOf(' '));
                    };
            function indexes(source, find) {

                for (var i = 0; i < source.length; ++i) {

                    if (source.substring(i, i + find.length) == find) {
                        result.push(i);
                    }
                }
            function formatLink (link){

                        var formattedLink =  "<a href=\""+link+"\">"+link+"<\/a>";
                        return formattedLink;

                    }

                _.each(result, function (index) {



                    var links = getFirstWord(comments.Answers.substring(index, comments.Answers.length));
                    obj[links] = formatLink(links);
                });

                return result;
            }
            if (!_.isUndefined(comments.Answers)) {

                indexes(comments.Answers, "http");

                _.mapKeys(obj, function(value, links) {

                    comments.Answers = comments.Answers.replace(links, value);

                return;
                });
            }
    });
```

What I'm currently getting:
[image]

Had to upload picture because even Stackoverflow converts the text to links

[image]

I also tried it without the "pre-line"

Comment: Can you provide some code, etc.?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What doesn't work in the code you provided? Is it anything wrong with it? If so, what is it? Also, what is the JQuery error you are receiving?

Comment: What's the response type? is it `text/html` ?

Comment: I sometimes get the feeling people are here to downvote and critisize. I mentioned what was wrong, the code does what it is supposed to do: the text that comes out isn't the format required as mentioned in the question. I need the links to be links and not text.

Comment: @AfshinGhazi please inspect the page and find out what's the response type?

Comment: @AfshinGhazi Nobody is here only to criticise. Community may seem severe sometimes but this is for the benefit of the question. If a question lacks important information, rest assured that we will request what is missing before posting any irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new angular tag: ng-bind-html in the view  and then as per example below updated code.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>


angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```